# Select statement on tables with the same name and schema but in different databases

Tags: mysql

I have a table that lists the names of the databases that have tables with the same schema. Each customer has a different database.

Is there a way to run a select on same table in multiple databases?

The first query I wrote was to get a list of databases concatenated the table name.

```
Select concat(database_name,'.','TableA') from dbnamelist
```

This results in output like

```
database1.TableA
database2.TableA
```

Now I want to select a value in the column type but across different tables.

```
Select type from database1.TableA,database2,TableA
```

Is it possible to do this in a single SQL statement?

Comment: *Is it possible to do this in a single SQL statement?* No. Create [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html). Use [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: Thank you! Prepared statement is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(table_schema, '.', tableA))
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name = 'tableA';
```

will generate the list you need.

Figure out what the query needs to look like (and I do not think your example is correct), and modify this `SELECT` to generate the desired query.

Then copy and paste it into mysql commandline tool to run it.